# How to change sheets on a multi-sheet drawing?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've turned a multi-sheet drawing into an svf for my forge viewer. I can't tell if it's only generating the first sheet or if I don't have a nav element to change sheets. Is there a way to change sheets?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following extension to your viewer so it will let you do a Document browse of all the models available.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/DocumentBrowser/

[image]